# Информация из бд не рендерится в шаблоне Wagtail

Tags: python, django

Есть модель:

```
class HomePage(Page):
   test = CharField(max_length=256, default='test')

   content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
      FieldPanel('test'),
   ]
```

Вывожу в шаблон, используя `{{ self.test }}`, а в шаблоне пусто. Хотя в бд поле имеет запись - `SELECT test FROM "home_homepage"` возвращает значение

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае используйте: {{ page.test }}

Comment: Постарайтесь писать немного более развернутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].